# WAMP Wordpress installation cannot get past step 1, loads indefinitely

Tags: localhost, local-installation

I am trying to install Wordpress on WAMP

I changed my localhost path to `localhost:11245` in the WAMP config file, so when I load my apache admin screen I go to `localhost:11245`

When I loaded Wordpress, `localhost:11245/wordpress`, it prompted me to enter the admin information, that is what I entered :

- Database Name : `wordpress`
- User Name : `wpadmin`
- Password : `blank`
- Database Host : `localhost:11245`
- Table prefix : `wp_`

When I click `Submit`, it loads indefinitely. Somehow I made it come up with the following error. I imagine this has something to do with me changing the port 
number.

> Welcome to WordPress. Before getting started, we need some information
>   on the database. You will need to know the following items before
>   proceeding.
>
> - Database name
> - Database username
> - Database password
> - Database host
> - Table prefix (if you want to run more than one WordPress in a
>     single database)
>
> If for any reason this automatic file creation doesn't work, don't
>   worry. All this does is fill in the database information to a
>   configuration file. You may also simply open wp-config-sample.php in a
>   text editor, fill in your information, and save it as wp-config.php.
>
> In all likelihood, these items were supplied to you by your Web Host.
>   If you do not have this information, then you will need to contact
>   them before you can continue. If you’re all ready…

How can I get it to install?

**EDIT**

I was able to get WAMP to route to `localhost`, then I ran `localhost/wordpress` and went through the setup screen again with these settings :

- Database Name : `wordpress`
- User Name : `root`
- Password : ``
- Database Host : `localhost`
- Table prefix : `wp_`

I just ran a php page with this info on it and it returned `Connection OK`

```
<?php 
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root',''); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
echo 'Connection OK'; mysql_close($link); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are the instructions i followed:

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/installing-wordpress-locally

Comment: I tried it with those instructions and I got a different error. `Error establishing a database connection`. Did you connect to `http://localhost` or did you have a port number like `http://localhost:1232`?

Comment: my sites are all localhost/folder_name where folder_name is the folder in my htdocs folder (i use xammp).  db connection error means you need to ensure your db name, user name and password in wp_config.php match the values you created in phpmyadmin

Comment: I tried it with root userID and that seemed to work, I must have not set up my wordpress database userID properly.